# Grammar description for language Java

Tags: java, syntax, grammar

I'm writing a bachelor's thesis on "Analysis of the source code in Java applications". I have a few points that must include written part. One of them is "a brief description of the grammar and writing Java." Since this is a bachelor thesis, sources of information must be verified - the books, the official site of Java, etc. Unfortunately I can not find this information on the Java website (maybe I'm just casually looking for). If possible, it is easier for me to use online resources than books.

Can anyone advise me where I found this information verified? Of course we were in school in certain subjects taught either syntax or semantics of Java, but it does not seem so "official source".

Thank you all.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

Comment: Thank you, it seems useable for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the official Java Specification from Oracle.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) is good place to start.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

For static code analysis in Java you can find some automated tools.

[Static Code Analysis Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java)

Comment: Sorry, but somehow I do not see what I could use from that link. I need to find official information that I could "rest" and are true. Maybe wrong I understand your reference. Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: For example Checkstyle (in the link I provided) does language semantics and grammar check. If you are using any Integrated Development Environment like Eclipse you can get plugins available. This automatically checks your source code based on your configuration.

Comment: If this is useful, please accept so others can get benefit of using this later.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried google scolar.
Scolar only gives proper scientific results.

for instance you might like [this article](http://books.google.nl/books?hl=nl&lr=&id=_Ed9tKi7blIC&oi=fnd&pg=PR3&dq=java%20syntax&ots=zF2eXhMVDk&sig=uGNoYqp6Bge32H9ho03SMqT68hE#v=onepage&q=java%20syntax&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot it, even though I've used it in the past.